# ContainsKey() dont find an object in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I was a homework, I had to implement some method. I can do the upload method, where I had to upload an dictionary in elements. If the Key had already in the Dictionary I had to update the Value. If the key wasn't in the Dictionary, I had to add that element. In Foreach I could do that.

In the method never true in the if case, only the else case execute. ( In other way I tried to `if(alcDictionary.Keys==alc)` -but isn't work). I don't know why. Somebody can explain me where is my problem? Why never execute the If case. (Always write out "dont find", and not the "find")

I've written this method with containsKey():

```
     public void Upload(Alcohol alc, int dl)
    {
        int d = 0;
        Alcohol s = null;
        if (alcDictionary.ContainsKey(alc))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("I find");
            d = alcDictionary[alc];
            alcDictionary[alc] = d + dl;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("dont find");
            alcDictionary.Add(alc, dl);
        }
```

With Foreach ( It works good!)

```
            int d = 0;
        Alcohol s = null;
        foreach (var item in alcDictionary)
        {
            if (item.Key.Equals(alc))
            {
                d = item.Value;
                s = item.Key;
            }
        }
        if (s != null)
        {
            alcDictionary[s] = d + dl;
        }
        else
        {
            alcDictionary.Add(alc, dl);
        }
```

Some other code:

```
    public Kocsma()
    {
        Upload(new Alcohol("Borsodi alc", 160, 4.6), 1000);
        Upload(new Alcohol("Pilsner Urquell", 250, 4.4), 800);
        Upload(new Alcohol("Soproni Ászok", 150, 4.5), 900);
        Upload(new Alcohol("Dreher Classic", 200, 5.2), 600);
    }


    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Alcohol b = new Alcohol("Borsodi alc", 160, 4.6); //34
        Alcohol c = new Alcohol("Bratista alc", 230, 4.5); // 51
        Alcohol d = new Alcohol("Soproni Ászok", 150, 4.5); // 33,3

        Kocsma pub = new Kocsma();

        pub.Upload(c, 300);
        pub.Upload(d, 450);
        pub.Upload(b, 100);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correctly override `GetHashCode()` in your key class.

`GetHashCode()` must return equal values for equal objects.

Comment: He should override Equals, too.

Comment: @zmbq: If you look at his `foreach` example, it's clear that he did.

Comment: No, it's not. Alc can actually be the same instance he used to add the item to the dictionary. The compiler warns you if you implement one and not the other, I'm betting he didn't implement either.

Comment: @zmbq: I believe `alc` is the same in both cases.

Comment: In homework I implemented the equals. But the getHashCode() didnt, and musnt implement other methods without the prof wrote to us... (and the GetHashCode() wasn't in the program, and didn't learn about) Maybe this is my program problem :)

Comment: And I just lost the bet, he did implement Equals :-)

Comment: @blaces: If this is a homework assignment, then either the professor didn't intend that you use a dictionary or he isn't a good professor.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: he isn't a good prof, never spoke about the GetHashCode()... This is very new for me, but I was in the all lesson. Thanks the answers! :)

Answer (score 2):

What is alc? If it's a class, you should override .Equals and .GetHashcode for dictionaries to work properly. If it's a structure, you don't need to worry about it.

I'm curious why your second version works, because `Item.Key.Equals(alc)` should show the same behavior.

Comment: ` public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Sör)
            {
                Sör other = (Sör)obj;
                return this.név == other.név;
            }
            return false;
        }`

Comment: that was my Equals method. But We didnt learn about GetHashcode. Thats new for me, maybe that way my problem